# How can I remove an image from google's search results?

Tags: google-chrome

So this business wants me to remove an image that comes up in googles little side window that sits on the right side of the search results. So when you type in "Gilbert Moving & Storage" in the search engine the window that sits on the right side of the search results has this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHIcy.png) Any Ideas on how I go about doing this?